# Displaying Message based current info from an xml

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following code and would like to display a message saying "Upper Elk River Recreational Activity - " then either "Safe, Caution, or Dangerous" based on the current outflow from the dam.  I thought I had this working but the current outflow is over 3000, which should be dangerous but it still shows safe.

```
$url2 = "http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/TFH_R.xml";
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file($url2);
?>
<style>
    .discharge-Safe {
        font-size: 20px;
        background: green;
        color: white;
    }
    .discharge-Caution {
        font-size: 20px;
        background: yellow;
        color: white;
    }
    .discharge-Dangerous {
        font-size: 20px;
        background: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<h4><?php
$discharge = (int) $xml2->RESULTSET[2]->ROW[48]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;
$discharge_range = [
    'Safe' => [ 'min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 500 ], 
    'Caution' => [ 'min_range' => 501, 'max_range' => 799 ], 
    'Dangerous' => [ 'min_range' => 800, 'max_range' => 9000  ]
];

$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};

echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">Upper Elk River Recreational Activity - '.$discharge_class($discharge).'</span>';
?></h4>
```

I made this change:

```
// last item
$discharge = $xml2->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[count($xml2->RESULTSET[1]->ROW)-1]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;

$discharge_range = [
    'safe'      => [ 'min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 499 ], 
    'caution'   => [ 'min_range' => 500, 'max_range' => 799 ], 
    'dangerous' => [ 'min_range' => 800, 'max_range' => 10000 ]
];

$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};

echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">Upper Elk River Recreational Activity-'.$discharge.'</span>';
?></h4
```

And now I get Upper Elk River Recreational Activity- 3,845 which is correct outflow number, but there is no color, based on the range this should be red.

If I change the echo back to the original code:

```
echo '<span class="discharge-'.$discharge_class($discharge).'">Upper Elk River Recreational Activity - '.$discharge_class($discharge).'</span>';
?></h4>
```

I get Upper Elk River Recreational Activity - , no range name?

Comment: Code works ok for me, I would guess that your `$discharge` variable doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: FWIW, I'd drop the `use ($discharge_range)` and put its declaration 
 inside the function, there's no need to dirty your global scope with it.

Comment: This is the link to the XML, [link] http://r7j8v4x4.map2.ssl.hwcdn.net/TFH_R.xml and I need the second resultset, the last row so row 48, and the avg hourly discharge, so RESULTSET[2]->ROW[48]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE.  I changed the row numbers, and it didn't matter, it always shows Safe.  I tried changing the name from safe to something else, and it changed in the browser.  So for whatever reason it's not reading the two other ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the array indexes in PHP, they are 0 based, so if you want the second result set and the 48th element, this should be...

```
$discharge = (int) $xml2->RESULTSET[1]->ROW[47]->AVG_HOURLY_DISCHARGE;
```

The second part to the problem is that the numbers with commas in them.  So the figures such as 3,845 are causing a problem with the numeric comparison.  The simplest way is to remove any commas...

```
$discharge_class = function ($value) use ($discharge_range) {
    $value = str_replace(",", "", $value);   // Remove commas
    foreach ($discharge_range as $key => $range) {
        if (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, ['options' => $range]) !== false) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I would have thought the same thing, for some reason it was only giving me an output of 3 when I was echoing just the outflow number.  I made an edit to my original post with what I got to echo the correct outflow number, but won't give me the correct range name when I want to echo that.

Comment: Added a new part to the answer.